# How to texture a rectangle with multiple textures in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to make a 2d map (for a game, think tiled world map) in OpenGL ES 2.0 for an android game. Basically, there are a few tile types that have different textures, and the map is randomly generated from these types, so from game-to-game the map changes but for the duration of a single game it stays the same.

My first thought was to generate a single large texture / image / bitmap (independent from OpenGL) beforehand basically stitching duplicate tile textures together to make the larger map, and then using this single texture for one large map rectangle. In theory I think this is simple and would work fine, but I'm worried that it won't scale well for larger maps and especially on mobile I'll run out of memory with such a large image map. Plus, there's a small set of tiles that are duplicated over and over so it seems like a tremendous waste to duplicate the pixel data in a big texture over and over.

My second thought was having many textures, one for each of the tile textures. But I'm not sure how this would work, texture-binding-wise, would I need the shaders to contain multiple texture references and within the shader have logic for using the right one?

Finally, I thought using a texture atlas could work, have one texture / image with all of the tile data in it, this would be relatively small. But I'm struggling to imagine how to get the maths to work out such that "tiles" or subsections of the map rectangle would use completely different texture coordinates.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Should I be using a rectangle for each tile? At least this way I can pass the shaders both vertex and texture coordinates for each tile independently. This seems easier, but also seems wrong since the map really is just one rectangle that won't be changing.

Answer (score 0):

> My first thought was to generate a single large texture...

- Actualy, something like this has already been used in id Software's id Tech since version 4. It's called MegaTexture. Basicaly, it's a big texture, which could also hold additional data.

> My second thought was having many textures...

- You don't need to hold all the textures in a shader. Do it like this:

  1. Implement a loop with n iterations, where n is how much different types of textures are used.
  2. Inside a loop, bind the current texture type.
  3. Pass any data, like position/color/texture coords to shaders.
  4. Draw all tiles that use the bounded texture. You could use `GLES30.glDrawElementsInstanced` or `GLES30.glDrawArraysInstanced` if you are targeting devices with GLES 3.x or an appropriate extension support. Otherwise, draw your tiles using `GLES20.glDrawArrays` or `GLES20.glDrawElements`.

  Shaders won't be complicated with this approach.

> Finally, I thought using a texture atlas could work...

- You could use loop here too and compute the texture coordinates for each tile type on CPU, then just pass them to shaders.

Considering your map is not changing through a game session, MegaTexture approach looks good. However, it depends on how large your map is and how much memory is available. Also, note that max texture size is limited. Max size differs from device to device but should be (AFAIK) equal or greater than screen size and at least 64 texels(16 for cube-mapped textures). You can get the maximum texture size on any device using `glGet(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE )`.